# Automatic call audio routing still asking for device

Tags: ios, audio, router, call

I have recently purchased new airpods and they were working good, but yesterday I think I didn't pair them properly and tried to make a phone call. Since then everytime I try to make a phone call even with airpods disconnected, it prompts me to choose an output device, even though I have set my call audio routing to automatic. It has happened to me once before with friends JBL bluetooth speaker, but I don't remember how I solved it. I think the problem faded away after a couple of days, but I'm not sure if it was due to me clicking something in settings or not...

Has anyone encountered the same problem? If so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it is a bit awkward, but I managed to solve my own problem. I went to:

```
Bluetooth settings -> MyAirPodsName -> forget this device
```

Then I paired my airpods again with my phone and tried to make a phone call. And sure it worked! Now when I have my airpods connected it chooses them automatically, if not, I can switch between "iPhone" and "speaker" as they are named in the list by tapping the speaker button.

I think it is some weird bug that prevents the call audio routing from selecting the device automatically so you have to select it explicitly everytime you call someone... It is a bit annoying, but it is easily fixable, so no big problem.